# script tag in doesnt work in my index.html

Tags: javascript, html, css

The script tag in index.html doesn't work. I have no idea why it isn't working. I have also tried add it into another file & giving it a link

```js
let stars = document.getElementById('stars')
let moon = document.getElementById('moon')
let mountain_behind = document.getElementById('mountain-behind')
let mountain_front = document.getElementById('mountain-front')
let btn = document.getElementById('btn')
let text = document.getElementById('text')
//let header = document.querySelector('header')

window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
  let value = window.screenY;
  stars.style.left = value * 0.25 + 'px'
  moon.style.top = value * 1.05 + 'px'
  mountain_behind.style.top = value * 0.5 + 'px'
  mountain_front.style.top = value * 0 + 'px'
  text.style.marginRight = value * 4 + 'px'
  text.style.marginTop = value * 1.5 + 'px'
  btn.style.marginTop = value * 1.5 + 'px'
  //header.style.top = value * 0.5 + "px"
})
```

```css
body, html { height: 1000px; }
```

```html
<section>
  <img src="img/stars.png" id="stars">
  <img src="img/moon.png" id="moon">
  <img src="img/mountains_behind.png" id="mountain-behind">
  <h2 id="text">Genesis 2k22</h2>
  <a href="#sec" id="btn" class="btn">Register Now</a>
  <img src="img/mountains_front.png" id="mountain-front">
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because your logic to retrieve the vertical scroll position is flawed. You need to calculate it from the offset and `clientY`:

```js
let stars = document.getElementById('stars')
let moon = document.getElementById('moon')
let mountain_behind = document.getElementById('mountain-behind')
let mountain_front = document.getElementById('mountain-front')
let btn = document.getElementById('btn')
let text = document.getElementById('text')
//let header = document.querySelector('header')

window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
  var doc = document.documentElement;
  var value = (window.pageYOffset || doc.scrollTop) - (doc.clientTop || 0);
  
  stars.style.left = value * 0.25 + 'px'
  moon.style.top = value * 1.05 + 'px'
  mountain_behind.style.top = value * 0.5 + 'px'
  mountain_front.style.top = value * 0 + 'px'
  text.style.marginRight = value * 4 + 'px'
  text.style.marginTop = value * 1.5 + 'px'
  btn.style.marginTop = value * 1.5 + 'px'
  //header.style.top = value * 0.5 + "px"
})
```

```css
body,
html {
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <img src="img/stars.png" id="stars">
  <img src="img/moon.png" id="moon">
  <img src="img/mountains_behind.png" id="mountain-behind">
  <h2 id="text">Genesis 2k22</h2>
  <a href="#sec" id="btn" class="btn">Register Now</a>
  <img src="img/mountains_front.png" id="mountain-front">
</section>
```

Comment: PS: I would also add that `top` (`left`, `margin` etc) CSS properties should not be used to create parallax, or any other kind of *motion* effects. Rather `transform: translate(x, y)` or the new CSS `translate: x y;`